# Python - append() operation in list comprehension resulting in memory balloon

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
2 GB RAM, 4 GB Swap
----
import re
fieldname_groups = ("(ip,clienthost,ip_addr)", "(username,user,id)")

srcgroup = [x.strip() for x in re.sub('[\(\)]+', '', fieldname_groups[0]).split(',')]
dstgroup = [x.strip() for x in re.sub('[\(\)]+', '', fieldname_groups[1]).split(',')]
if not srcgroup or not dstgroup: raise Exception("No srcgroup or dstgroup specified!")

# srcgroup is now ['ip', 'clienthost', 'ip_addr']
# dstgroup is now ['username', 'user', 'id']

# Now append the string '.keyword' to a copy of every string in each list
[srcgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup]
[dstgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in dstgroup]

# srcgroup should now be ['ip', 'clienthost', 'ip_addr', 'ip.keyword', 'clienthost.keyword', 'ip_addr.keyword']
# dstgroup should be similar
```

Every time I run this code, once I hit the list comprehensions the memory balloons up and the process is killed.

I'm not understanding what the problem is here; I feel like this is something I do all the time yet this time it's not working, so it's probably an amateur mistake but I'd appreciate any help in sorting it out. I've even tried rewriting the code to use a standard for loop but it still explodes.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect it will happen with this comprehension? `[srcgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup]` - you are adding to list while you're iterating it.

Comment: yeah, one thing for sure - don't change the collection while you are iterating over it

Comment: Ugh, I didn't think Python would actually let me do that. I misunderstood it to be working off of a copy or something. If I replace the comprehensions with [srcgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in [y for y in srcgroup]] it does work. Post your critique as an answer and I'll give you the credit :)

Comment: A list comprehension is not a one-line version of a `for` loop. You're creating a list of `None` references that you immediately discard.

Comment: @Ivan ok, I made an answer :)

Comment: Appending to a list in a list comprehension is still a bad idea. It wastes space creating a list of `None`. Just write `for x in g[:]: g.append(...)`

Comment: @MaxieBall : or use a generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding to a list, while you are iterating it -> the memory will grow up indefinitely:

```
[srcgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup]
[dstgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in dstgroup]
```

The solution is to iterate over a copy:

```
[srcgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup[:]]
[dstgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in dstgroup[:]]
```

Edit:

Better idea would be simplify things a little bit (from answers below):

```
srcgroup = ['ip', 'keyword']

srcgroup.extend([f'{x}.keyword' for x in srcgroup])
print(srcgroup)
```

Will output:

```
['ip', 'keyword', 'ip.keyword', 'keyword.keyword']
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to extend a list is to use the `extend` method.

```
srcgroup = [x.strip() for x in re.sub('[\(\)]+', '', fieldname_groups[0]).split(',')]
srcgroup.extend(['%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup])
```

Note that it is critical that the argument to `extend` is a new list, and not a generator expression that iterates `srcgroup` as new elements are added to `srcgroup`.

Under no circumstances should you use a list comprehension solely for the side effect of the expression. Use

```
for x in ...:
    ...
```

instead of

```
[... for x in ...]
```

Comment: I get and agree with your usage of extend (and am changing my code to do just that), but wouldn't the "for x in ..." method still have me modifying the list as I'm iterating it? That was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: No, because the list comprehension creates a new list before `srcgroup.extend` ever runs. You are essentially making a copy of the input first, and that copy is what `extend` iterates over.

Answer (score 2):

As @Andrej Kesely said, you're adding elements to the list you're iterating **while iterating**. So, you keep adding elements to the loop, and thus the loop never ends.

I'm not sure what you want exactly, but maybe what you should do is create a new list on the fly to iterate over it, instead of the one you're adding the elements to, as such:

```
[srcgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup[:]]  # Notice the [:]
[dstgroup.append('%s.keyword' % x) for x in dstgroup[:]]  # Notice the [:]
```

Adding the [:] at the end of the list name slices it keeping all the elements, and saves it to a new object on the fly, so the error doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

In a list comprehension, you should have side-effects (such as appending items to a list). The list comprehension creates a new list, you don't need to `append` items manually.

If you want to replace each element in the list, you can create a new list and replace the old one:

```
scrgroup = [('%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup]
dstgroup = [('%s.keyword' % x) for x in dstgroup]
```

However, if you want to add to the list a copy of each element with that formatting, you need to extend it:

```
scrgroup.extend([('%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup])
dstgroup.extend([('%s.keyword' % x) for x in dstgroup])
```

However, to reduce memory usage, you could use a generator in that case:

```
scrgroup.extend((('%s.keyword' % x) for x in srcgroup))
dstgroup.extend((('%s.keyword' % x) for x in dstgroup))
```

Comment: Ha, no wonder I thought I do this all the time-- that's the syntax I *meant* to write ;)

Answer (score 1):

As was stated above, your problem is that you're appending to a collection you're iterating on. That being the case, copying an entire list is somewhat wasteful. To avoid, creating another copy of the list, you could do:

```
srcgroup.extend( ['%s.keyword' % x for x in srcgroup] )
dstgroup.extend( ['%s.keyword' % x for x in dstgroup] )
```

which would modify the list in-place. Here's a performance comparison:

```
timeit.timeit('arr = range(1000); arr = arr.extend( [x + 1 for x in arr] )')
53.47952483119644
timeit.timeit('arr = range(1000); arr = [arr.append(x + 1) for x in arr[:]]')
118.02281077109734
```

As you can see, my suggestion takes half the time (although they're both still O(n)).